# Can't open rails app, even if server is running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localhost

I've been developing a rails app with a VM and vagrant. Until yesterday, everything was working fine. However, when I tried to run the server and open the browser, it wasn't working. I tried on Chrome, Firefox and Safari, but the error persists on all three. I checked my dev logs, and this is what it says.

Yesterday's log:

```
Started GET "/" for 10.0.2.2 at 2013-12-11 06:38:31 +0000 Processing by HomeController#index as HTML   Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (43.6ms) Completed 200 OK in 159ms (Views: 158.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

and today's log says:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-12 19:02:04 +0000
  [1m[36mActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.4ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"[0m
Processing by HomeController#index as */*
  Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (212.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 595ms (Views: 555.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
  [1m[36mActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.5ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"[0m
  [1m[35mActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
```

Could anyone explain why the address it's trying to connect to appears to be different? And what needs to be done in order to be able to connect to it again?

Thanks.